# Payara tools plugin eclipse [Not found]

Tags: eclipse, jsf, plugins, eclipse-marketplace

Since 24 January 2023 im trying to install payara tools or glass fish tools for deploy a jsf application. I tried doing the marketplace and it gives me error also  tried to install from their repository and the link gives me 404 not found...

What's happening??? It's only me? or they change the method to install?

I'm using payara 5 and eclipse 2021 r2 enterprise.

Repository link from the marketplace

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/payara/ecosystem-eclipse-plugin/release-artifacts/repository/latest

And tried installing from the marketplace place and says that can't find solution.

Comment: Looks like reported issue https://github.com/payara/ecosystem-support/issues/62

Comment: thanks for the reply, i cant see any response from them (glassfish)  maybe i should use tomcat or another server for deploy ?